# How to qualify cells to include in addition (Excel)

Tags: excel

I have a column of data that ranges from about 0-1500.

What I've been able to do so far is use the count function to create a table of how many of the data lie in certain ranges (0-50, 51-100, 101-500, etc)

How could I instead sum up the numbers in each column which are part of the above subgroups? Such as, the sum of all values between 0-50, the sum of all values between 51-100, etc.

I know some java, in which I would run a for loop with an if statement, but in excel I'm not sure how to use the if statement and apply it to a whole column.

Appreciate any advice.

Comment: Use SUMIF() or SUMIFS(). These functions work very similar to the COUNTIF() or COUNTIFS() you already used, just that they don't count but sum up.

Comment: SUMIF(A:A,"<50") something similar to this but for all columns.